# What style is this thesis?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, thesis, drop-cap

Does anyone know how to reproduce the headers and the chapter/section styles of this thesis?

http://www.stat.washington.edu/~ebfox/publications/ebfox_thesis.pdf

To be more specific, how does one achieve the following.

a) The double line horizontal line below Chapter 1 (for example), followed by the thicker horizontal in the header with the chapter or section name above it in the following pages.

b) The nice squares before (sub)section names such as "1.1.1 Chapter Background".

c) The enlarged first letter of each chapter.

Below is an image from a page taken from the thesis that shows b) and the second part of a).

[image]

Comment: These types of questions have been asked before; it looks pretty standard, but the best person to ask would be [the author](http://www.stat.washington.edu/~ebfox/)

Comment: @cmhughes in my humble opinion, the style for chapter and section headers is not pretty standard; it is easily achieved (using `titlesec`, for example), but still I would consider this as a valid question, so I voted to reopen it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina ok, sounds good :) perhaps you could work with the OP to narrow the scope of the question and make it more specific- mine was the final vote, not the first :)

Comment: Also it should not depend so much on the referenced PDF being still available.

Comment: Well you can always wait for Gonzalos answer and then retroactively add examples to your question ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The formatting for the sectional units can be achieved using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; the headers can be obtained using the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package; the lettrine for the first letter of each chapter can be produced with the `\lettrine` command from the [`lettrine`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) package. A little example:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\pagestyle{fancy}

% chapter heading formatting
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\sffamily}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}  
  {\titlerule\vskip2pt\titlerule\vskip20pt\Huge\bfseries\filleft}
% section heading formatting
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\sffamily}{\rule[.12ex]{8pt}{8pt}}{0.5em}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries\sffamily}{\rule[.12ex]{8pt}{8pt}~\thesubsection}{0.5em}{}

% header/footer
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[ER]{\footnotesize\sffamily\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OL]{\footnotesize\sffamily\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[EL,OR]{\bfseries\thepage}

% redefinition of the plain style
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\bfseries\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{% 
\markright{Sec.~\thesection.\quad#1}} 

\renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}
\lettrine{I}{n} quisque ullamcorper placerat ipsum. Cras nibh. Morbi vel justo vitae lacustincidunt ultrices. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. In
hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer tempus convallis augue. Etiam facilisis.
Nunc elementum fermentum wisi. Aenean placerat. Ut imperdiet, enim sed
gravida sollicitudin, felis odio placerat quam, ac pulvinar elit purus eget enim.
Nunc vitae tortor. Proin tempus nibh sit amet nisl. Vivamus quis tortor vitae
risus porta vehicula.
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[4]
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\lipsum[1-30]

\end{document}
```

Some images of the resulting document; the first page of a chapter:

[image]

Fragments of some inner pages showing the headers:

[image]

[image]